# Flutter: Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to add an image in the background. I found this code snippet here in StackOverflow.

```
SizedBox.expand(
        // -> 01
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5561184.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover, // -> 02
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

this worked quite well for me in this code:

```
enter codeimport 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  final int _picState;

  final VoidCallback _picStateChange;

  final Function _quizStarted;

  Welcome(this._quizStarted, this._picState, this._picStateChange);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          SizedBox.expand(
            // -> 01
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5561184.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover, // -> 02
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
              child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const Spacer(),
                Text(
                  'Start Application',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3?.copyWith(
                        color: Colors.white54,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Spacer(),
                TextField(
                  onTap: () => _picStateChange(),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    focusColor: Colors.amber,
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
                    hintText: 'ENTER YOUR NAME HERE',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                        wordSpacing: 2,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        decoration: TextDecoration.underline),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () => _quizStarted(),
                  child: Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                        gradient: (LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.lime, Colors.blueGrey.shade700],
                            begin: Alignment.topRight,
                            end: Alignment.bottomLeft))),
                    child: Text('START THE APPLICATION',
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .button
                            ?.copyWith(color: Colors.white38)),
                  ),
                ),
                Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

but when I used the same code in another section(the one below) the error "**Failed assertion: line 1927 pos 12: 'hasSize'**" appears

```
**import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback ansk;
  final String gimme_Da_Answer;

  Answer(this.ansk, this.gimme_Da_Answer);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          SizedBox.expand(
            // -> 01
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5561184.jpg'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fitHeight, // -> 02
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 18, horizontal: 17),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () => ansk(),
                child: (Container(
                  child: Text(gimme_Da_Answer,textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: Colors.cyan.shade800,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 4),
                      color: Colors.blueAccent.shade100.withOpacity(0.4),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15))),
                )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}**
```

^the code that shows error for me
THANKS A LOT!!!

Comment: wrap your stack with the `material` widget like `Scaffold`

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs here because the Widget is looking for a size since `fit` has been set on the BoxDecoration. To solve this issue, set a width and height on the `Container`.

```dart
Container(
  // set Container dimension
  width: 100, 
  height: 100,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: NetworkImage(),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
)
```